# How to check your Website’s files to figure out whitespace and remove it in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, removing-whitespace, xml-sitemap

how to check your site’s files to figure out whitespace in wordpress?

i do not know how to do that. Please tell me the procedure and steps to do that. I tried using script it works but i need a permanent solution. Because of this i am getting xml sitemap error. please resolve this problem.

Comment: Where does this whitespace appear on your WordPress site? Please [edit] your question to give more details, or ask another question if this one is closed.

Comment: What is the error? What does the xml sitemap look like? How do you generate it? With a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To address whitespace issues, you can begin by using a reliable code editor or IDE (Integrated Development Environment) to inspect your site's files.

Look for unnecessary spaces at the beginning or end of lines, as well as extra line breaks. Utilize the "Find and Replace" feature with regular expressions to clean up excess whitespace efficiently.

If you're seeking a more permanent solution, consider configuring your code editor to automatically remove trailing spaces and enable linting plugins that highlight whitespace concerns during development.